# Ejecutar dos programas al mismo tiempo

Tags: python, python-3.x

Imaginemos que tengo dos scripts escritos un python.

El primero se llama `programa_1.py` y el segundo `programa_2.py`.

Para ser ejecutado, y debido a que abre unos archivos particulares, el `programa_1.py` necesita correrse en un directorio denominado, pongamos:

```
C:\Users\test_1
```

Para ser ejecutado, y debido a que abre otros archivos particulares, el `programa_2.py` necesita correrse en un directorio denominado, pongamos:

```
C:\Users\test_2
```

El programa_1 genera un archivo llamado `datos_1.csv`

El programa_2 genera un archivo llamado `datos_2.csv`

Mi pregunta:

¿Puedo crear un script nuevo que ejecute ambos programas al mismo tiempo?

Comment: ¿Interaccionan o comparten archivos en modo de escritura en algún momento ambos scripts o son completamente independientes entre si?

Comment: En principio, pongamos que son completamente independientes. Porque leen archivos distintos, cada uno en su directorio.

Comment: Pyring mintras compartan archivos de solo lectura no hay problema, otro tema es que ambos scripts usen un mismo archivo para escribir datos,. en ese caso hay que establecer mecanismos de sincronización adecuados para no llevarse sorpresas desagradables ;) He creado una respuesta, mira a ver si satisface tus requerimientos. No se si tus script necesitan parámetros de entrada o no o si estos son diferentes para cada uno, si tienes problemas cometa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si quieres que se ejecuten de forma completamente paralela (los hilos están limitados en CPython por el GIL) necesitas crear un proceso para cada script.

Tratándose de dos script independientes puedes crear un tercer script y usar [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) para crear un proceso por cada script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 

import subprocess


# Iterable con las rutas de los scripts
scripts_paths = ("C:/Users/test_1/script1.py", "C:/Users/test_2/script2.py")

# Creamos cada proceso    
procesos = [subprocess.Popen(["python", script]) for script in scripts_paths]

# Esperamos a que todos los subprocesos terminen.
for proceso in procesos:
    proceso.wait()

# Resto de código a ejecutar cuando terminen todos los subprocesos.
```

Si necesitas o quieres comprobar si los procesos terminaron o no correctamente puedes usar una lista por compresión que contenga los códigos de salida retornados por `wait`:

```
exit_codes = [p.wait() for p in p1, p2]
```

Generalmente se retorna 0 si el programa terminó con éxito,  por lo que puedes condicionar el comportamiento posterior en función de ello:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 

import subprocess


scripts_paths = ("C:/Users/test_1/script1.py", "C:/Users/test_2/script2.py")

ps = [subprocess.Popen(["python", script]) for script in scripts_paths]
exit_codes = [p.wait() for p in ps]

if not any(exit_codes):
    print("Todos los procesos terminaroin con éxito")
else:
    print("Algunos procesos terminaron de forma inesperada.")
```

Si los scripts requieren argumentos se les pueden pasar también sin problemas.

Si necesitas que ambos procesos interacciones entre ellos de forma segura deberá usar [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) y establecer mecanismos seguros de comunicación entre ellos.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta. Voy a ver si soy capaz de utilizar algo similar a este código. La única interacción, en principio y por ahora, sería que necesitaría combinar en un solo archivo csv los dos csv que independientemente crea cada script. Eso sí, los csv que se crean tienen las mismas columnas, estructura y cabeceras. Ergo, ¿puedo simplemente añadir directamente al final de tu código un nuevo fragemnto de código para abrir y combinar los archivos csv?

Comment: Si, esa es una solución. Coloca al final de este script (después del for encargado de llamar al método `wait`) el código encargado de unir ambos ficheros, este código solo se ejecutara cuando todos los procesos terminen. Si quisiera hacerlo de forma paralela también entonces lo que se suele hacer es dedicar un tercer proceso encargado solo a la escritura del fichero y los demás le envían los datos a una cola de forma segura, pero esto ya requieres modificaciones mayores.

Comment: Muchas gracias @FJSevilla. Parece que funciona bien con una versión de los códigos que tengo. Si me surgen más dudas pregunto, pero muchas gracias por la orientación.

Answer (score 1):

Si deseas usar threading en python 3 debes hacer estas pequeñas modificaciones de execfile a exec open como el ejemplo

```
import threading

def ejecutar_doc1():
    exec(open("C:\Users\test_1.py").read())
def ejecutar_doc2():
    exec(open("C:\Users\test_2.py").read())

hilo1 = threading.Thread(target=ejecutar_doc1)
hilo2 = threading.Thread(target=ejecutar_doc2)
hilo1.start()
hilo2.start()
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta @Pepo Gonzalez